# Select flyspell via a variable in a file

Tags: emacs, local-variables, flyspell

1. Question:

How can i select flyspell automatically by an EMACS Variable in my file 
(not via the .emacs configuration file!), just for that file, similar like I select the ispell dictionary just for that file

EXAMPLE abc.tex:

---SNIP---

```
text text ..

text text ..

<!-- LocalXIspellDict: de -->
<!-- HERE SHOULD GO THE SOLUTION -->
```

---SNIP---

Second Question:

How can I achieve that -- whenever I open a TeX-File, i. e., XXX.tex -- flyspell is automatically selected by configuring my init.el file? Meaning, flyspell is selected depending on the filename extension.

Comment: Should be<!-- Local IspellDict: de -->

Comment: You really should ask two separate questions. It will help other users in the future who search for an answer to a problem similar to only one of the two.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the first-line file variables statement is a commented local variables block like this:

```tex
% Local Variables:
% eval: (flyspell-mode 1)
% ispell-local-dictionary: "german"
% End:
```

(n.b. As of Emacs 24, while still applicable to major modes, the `mode: MINOR-MODE` syntax is deprecated, and `eval` should be used instead).

See the manual for details:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Specifying File Variables")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Also: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FileLocalVariables

Answer (score 1):

The second part is rather simple: Just add `flyspell-mode` to the `mode-hook` for every mode that you want to use with `flyspell`.

This enables flyspell whenever `text-mode` is enabled (which is basically always):

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()  (flyspell-mode 1)))
```

You probably want to use `tex-mode-hook`.

For the file: Put this on the beginning of the file and flyspell should be entered whenever you find that file.

```
-*- mode: flyspell; -*-
```

Comment: It worked with:    (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()  (flyspell-mode 1)))

Comment: @user1165430 Which just means that you are using `AuCTeX` and not the standard TeX package distributed with emacs. Welcome to SO btw. Please read the faq to get to know the site better and to understand upvoting and accepting answers.

Answer (score -1):

Using file-local-variables: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html

```
% Local Variables:
%   ispell-local-dictionary: "american"
% End:
```

Comment: The [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) says "Do not use the mode keyword for minor modes."